# Variable in active record query, ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try to pass in a variable in a active record query:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
        @tags = @user.tag_list
        i = 0
        @tags.each do |tag|
          i= i + 1
          @tag"#{i}" = Info.tagged_with(tag.name)
        end
      end
    end
```

As you can see, I try to pass in a variable in @tag. I tried `@tag"#{i}"`, but this doesn't work. What do I need to type in, to get `@tag` with the number i? My goal is the following output:

```
@tag1
@tag2
@tag3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`instance_variable_set()`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) method:

```
instance_variable_set(:"@tag#{i}", Info.tagged_with(tag.name))
```